# fill input fields with first searched item in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use a code in ajax to auto fill the input fields when a matching item is selected from dropdown list .

```
$('#company_name_1').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: 'company_name',
               row_num : 1
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[3],
                        value: code[3],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                    
    $('#name_1').val(names[2]);
        $('#barcodescanr').val(names[0]);
        $('#surname_1').val(names[1]);
        $('#firm_1').val(names[4]);
        $('#info').val(names[5]);
        $('#scanbartime').val(names[6]);
        $('#id').val(names[7]);
        $('#custId').val(names[8]);
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }               
});
```

My question is how i will automatically fill input fields of html with the values of first searched item without clicking on it?Thanks

Comment: Can you possibly make a jsFiddle? Also I assume you are using a jQuery-plugin?

Comment: i am new and i do not know how to do it

Comment: Yes i am using jquery

Comment: jQuery and jQuery plugins are different things. Not everyone may be familiar with what plugin you are using. [`autocomplete`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is not a native function of jQuery so its good to specify what plugins are using. You can go to jsfiddle.net to make an example so we can see what's going on.